# Error when using catkin_make command

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was going through this tutorial : http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Markers%3A%20Basic%20Shapes

I went step by step through the tutorial. Everything went well until i tried executing the command: catkin_make

It gives me error:

> The specified base path
> "/home/rajesh/using_markers" contains
> a package but "catkin_make" must be
> invoked in the root of workspace

I don't know how to fix this error before proceeding with the tutorial. I appreciate any help.

Thanks and regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251130/error-when-using-catkin_make-command/) by [Werewolf_86](https://answers.ros.org/users/28918/werewolf_86/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2017-01-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should go through this tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials) to learn how to use workspaces and packages.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2017-01-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1